# How to set value NULL to a field in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've a `Table` called `journals` in SqlAlchemy that has one of the following Columns:

```
Column('type', String(128))
```

Then I've `mapper` that maps `journals` to `Journals` python class:

```
mapper(Journals, journals);
```

I want to insert a new row in `journals` and set `type` to `NULL`.

What would be the corresponding Python type to NULL?

Here's example:

```
self.type = NULL;
```

There is no `NULL` type in Python so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You should use `None`.

Comment: Please make proper answer so i can accepts ok?!! thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert NULL value in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959336/how-to-insert-null-value-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `None`. `None` is the equivalent to `NULL` in Python.

Comment: Thanks this work! you also bounty = 100 karmas. :))))) because i good people :))))