# How to insert NULL value in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've a `Table` with the following column:

```
Column('type', String(128))
```

How do I set this column to NULL when inserting a new row in database?

I tried doing this:

```
self.type = NULL;
```

There is no `NULL` type in Python so I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Instead of trying

```
self.type = NULL
```

try as [Yaroslav Admin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377864/yaroslav-admin)

```
self.type = None
```

As Python's equivalent for NULL is None.

Comment: This actually insert "null" in the column. If you want your field to be actually nothing, use sqlalchemy's `null()`. Check Ilja Everilä 's answer for more details

Answer (score 34):

I know this is an old thread but this worked for me

```
self.type = sqlalchemy.sql.null()
```

Comment: for me it's also available as simply `sqlalchemy.null()` (v1.2.5)

Comment: This is useful if you have a JSONB column because there is a difference between `sqlalchemy.sql.null()` - which is treated as SQL NULL - and None which is treated as JSON "null" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

As the other answers have pointed out, an explicit NULL can be inserted by passing `None`, or in case of SQLAlchemy a [`null()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.null) construct, as the value. In fact PEP-249 "DB-API v2.0" clearly states this in ["Type Objects and Constructors"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#type-objects-and-constructors):

> SQL NULL values are represented by the Python `None` singleton on input and output.

As a third option one can simply omit the column, if it is nullable:

```
t = Table('t', metadata,
          Column('a', Integer),
          Column('b', Integer))

stmt = t.insert().values(a=1)
engine.execute(stmt)
```

would effectively insert a new row `(1, NULL)` in the table `t`, because a value was not provided for column `b`. The same applies for mapped classes, which I suppose the original question is actually using (because of the `self`):

```
class T(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = Column(Integer)
    b = Column(Integer)

session.add(T(a=1))
session.commit()
```

again effectively results in `(default, 1, NULL)` being inserted.