# What to insert into Postgres json type column if value is None

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

psycopg2 inserts null into a column when inserting None.

```
...
foo=json.dumps(insertObj.get('foo', None)),

...

db.session.add(s)
db.session.commit()
```

The value in the column is a string 'null' not the database type `null` which looks like `<null>` in the database manager. I thought it should insert database type null for None (see this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959336/how-to-insert-null-value-in-sqlalchemy)).

What should be inserted into a json column for an empty json value for best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think `NULL` is best practice for missing data, regardless of data type.

Use `NULL` / `None` when you don't have a json document to store, and you can then use the same idiom to pick or omit rows with where your json is `NULL` as you do with columns of other types.

This does however mean that when you fetch records, you have to expect that the json column can sometimes be null, and that needs special handling, but again, this is no different than other columns that allow nulls.

update:

As the OP already realized and is evident from the code snippet provided, the issue is that None is being dumped by json.dumps as a string, which is then inserted into the database.

psycopg2 provides a json adapter for postgresql, which can be used here.

change

```
foo=json.dumps(insertObj.get('foo', None))
```

to

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json
foo= Json(insertObj.get('foo', None))
```

Comment: the problem is NULL isn't being insert for Python's None, it is inserting a string 'null' into the database

Comment: nevermind found out it was because i was using json.dumps

Comment: ah, good thing, i was searching through my code to see why i was able to insert nulls in my json columns, and yet the answer was right in the code example you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this answer. If the variable is set and is null e.g.

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json
someVar = None
foo = Json(someVar)
```

then it will still add `null` as a string. To get around this do:

```
foo = Json(someVar) if someVar else None
```