# Flask SqlAlchemy: Returning None for JSON type inserts 'null' string, not real NULL

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask SqlAlchemy. I'm inserting data into a Postgres DB and there is a `JSON` column type. When there is no data, I return `None` with the intention that that will set NULL into the column. This is what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062911/1005607).

```
if someCondition:
    json_obj = json.dumps(my_dict)
    return json_obj
else:
    return None # this inserts a 'null' string incorrectly
    # Only this works correctly:
    return null() # imported from sqlalchemy,
```

But I see that this inserts a `"null"` string. The only way to get a real NULL is to use `sqlalchemy.null()`. Someone else noticed the same thing in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959336/how-to-insert-null-value-in-sqlalchemy). Below is the difference from the two approaches. Can someone confirm that `None` should **not** be used for NULL insertion, to clear up the confusion?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is the default behavior.

The `JSON` and `JSONB` column type can be initialized with the parameter `none_as_null` set to `True`. This parameter is by default `False`.

The [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON) for reference.