# How to handle NaT values in oracle

Tags: oracle

I've a doubt regarding NaT value in Oracle.

I'm using Oracle database and python.

There's a common table between two databases and we're trying to sync it. If there's any mismatch in source and destination table then value should get inserted from source to destination.

There's one column of date type and it is having null values and while getting inserted it from source to destination, the null value is getting inserted as default value rather than null. But we want it as null only. How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by default? Please post a table definition

Comment: As you can see in the destination table image, it is inserting some particular date for all the null values or NaT values where person_id = 4

Comment: I see the result, but I cannot **guess** the reason (though, I can with unknown probability). So please provide a setup to reproduce the issue

Comment: suppose the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32959336/5841306) would help your issue.

Comment: Basically we've two db source and destination and the task is to sync them. There's a common in between them i.e. demo_1 and the number of records in source and dest db are same then no change but if record is present in source and not present in dest then record should get inserted in dest.

Comment: now the real challenge comes. So the table has 3 columns person id of no type , name of str type and dob of date type. In person_id and name column null values cannot get inserted but in dob, null value can get inserted. So there is one record where person_id = 4 which was present in source and not in dest. And dob field is null for that particular record in source table. So while getting inserted in dest table it is not storing null but some date. That null value is shown as NaT in python where as in db it is null.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `default` works; for the following table (whose `name` column has the default value set to `LF`)

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id       number,
  3     name     varchar2(10) default 'LF');

Table created.
```

let's do some inserts. First, specify both columns to be inserted and put a value into one row's `name` column, and let it be `null` for another:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, name)
  2    select 1, 'Little' from dual union all
  3    select 2, null     from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Little
         2                   --> if you expected LF to be inserted into the
                             --> NAME column, it wasn't. Why? Because you
                             --> explicitly said that you want to put NULL in there
```

But, if you omit the `name` column completely:

```
SQL> insert into test (id) values (3);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Little
         2
         3 LF            --> aha! Now we got the default value here!

SQL>
```

That's because Oracle did it that way (as described in [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) documentation:

> The `DEFAULT` clause lets you specify a value to be assigned to the column if a subsequent `INSERT` statement omits a value for the column.

There's more to read; have a look, if you want.

---

What does it mean for you? I don't know, you didn't post code you use to copy data from one table to another.

Comment: You've missed `on null` addition of the `default`, that's why I've requested the table definition. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=35bbff7b297a7bbcdf5afe1efad289da)

Answer (score 0):

> There's a common table between two databases and we're trying to sync it. If there's any mismatch in source and destination table then value should get inserted from source to destination.

You have not give the table definitions nor your python code but a simple solution is to create a database link from one database to the other and then not use python for the comparison and, instead, use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING table_name@remote_link src
ON (dst.col1 = src.col1 AND dst.col2 = src.col2 AND dst.col3 = src.col3)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (col1, col2, col3)
  VALUES (src.col1, src.col2, src.col3);
```